# promql get sum of metric in different time ranges

Tags: grafana, promql

I've the following promql query:

```
count(max(http_response_result_code{} > 0 )) by (name)
```

Which returns:

```
Time                          Value
2023-08-05 03:50:00           1
2023-08-05 05:00:00           1
```

I'm trying to sum these values which should be "2" but cannot get it sorted with sum function:

```
sum(count(max(http_response_result_code{} > 0 )) by (name))
```

Any ideas? Should be simple but not working...

Answer (score 0):

To aggregate something over time you, perhaps unsurprisingly, need to use [`<aggregation>_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) functions.

In the case you described in question your query probably should look like this:

```
sum_over_time((count(max(http_response_result_code{} > 0 )) by (name))[$__range:])
```

Here aggregation will happen over time range selected in your dashboard. If you need aggregation to happen over some predefined constant period of time, use range selector like this instead `[1h:]`.

---

Couple thoughts unrelated to your problem. Query

```
count(max(http_response_result_code{} > 0 )) by (name)
```

looks strange: there is no reason for `by (name)` clause in count, since `max` will return vector with no labels.

Additionally, your initial query will always return 1, if it returns anything.

I have suspicion, that you probably wanted something like this:

```
count(max by (name) (http_response_result_code{}) > 0)
```